# Gap between columns in Bootstrap Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

i am doing a grid layout containing 12 columns,is there any way to provide gap between columns without custom css

my partial is like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-3">
some content 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
some content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
some content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
some content
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

i want some gap between each column with out any offset?

Comment: padding? or border? ......

Comment: not padding of content..i need each column(col-xs-3) should have some space between them.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/Lmabv9UUEM use border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Bootstrap uses `box-sizing:border-box` and `float` to set the columns is better if you use some value on the `border` to create the gap:

```
.col-xs-3 {
   border:2px solid #fff; /*Color of the Background*/
}
```

Check the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Lmabv9UUEM)